# where can i Put Soap Action?

Tags: java, web-services, soap

```
public class SimpleHTTPRequest {
    String envelope1="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
    "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:tns=\"urn:insertdata\"" +
    " targetNamespace=\"urn:insertdata\">"+
    "<soap:Body>"+
    "<insertdata>"+
    "<name xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">ghjghj</name>"+
    "<phone xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">1111</phone>"+
    "<email xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">ascom</email>"+
    "<score xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">12</score>"+
    "</insertdata>"+
    "</soap:Body>"+
    "</soap:Envelope>";
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         String url="http://url/iphone_soap_server.php/insertdata";
          String soapAction="http://urkl/iphone_soap_server.php/insertdata/insertdata";
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    OutputStreamWriter wr = null;
    BufferedReader rd  = null;
    StringBuilder sb = null;
    String line = null;
    URL serverAddress = null;
    String data = "width=50&height=100";
    try {
        serverAddress = new URL("http://url/soap-server.php?wsdl");

        connection = null;

        //Set up the initial connection
        connection = (HttpURLConnection)serverAddress.openConnection();

        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());


        writer.write(data);
        writer.flush();




        rd  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        sb = new StringBuilder();

        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line + '\n');
        }

        System.out.println(sb.toString());

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ProtocolException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        //close the connection, set all objects to null
        connection.disconnect();
        rd = null;
        sb = null;
        wr = null;
        connection = null;
    }
}
}
```

I want consume the soap web services From Java where can i put the Soap Action IN this code...
Thanks in Advance.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using SOAP over HTTP, in general the SOAP Action is inserted in the `SOAPAction` HTTP header in the request. See the standard here: http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383528

> The SOAPAction HTTP request header field can be used to indicate the
>   intent of the SOAP HTTP request. The value is a URI identifying the
>   intent. SOAP places no restrictions on the format or specificity of
>   the URI or that it is resolvable. An HTTP client MUST use this header
>   field when issuing a SOAP HTTP Request.

So what you want is (assuming `soapAction` is set to the correct value):

```
connection.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", soapAction);
```

Comment: how can i pass soap request through xml in Java please let me know

Comment: can i put soapaction like this ?

Comment: String SOAPAction ="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style/ZMATERIALS_DETAILS";

Comment: i am adding namspace and method name from wsdl ?